# how to confirm ssl certificate will take over after intermediate

Tags: ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

Sorry, this is probably a dumb question, but just want some assurance...
Installed my first SSL certificate on an IIS 7 server and just want to know if there's a way to verify the SSL certificate will work when the intermediate expires. Want to make sure because I will be out of town when it does expire.  The installation seemed to go successfully and if I look up the domain using a third party verification site, it says it good, just that it expires soon.

If I open the server certificates in the IIS manager, it shows that one expires soon, and then another listed that expires in two years. Is this all I need to know and just trust things work right, or is there something else I need to look for/do?

Thanks,
David K.

Comment: Did you actually assign/bind the new cert to the site?

Comment: I believe I did. followed the instructions at http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4801/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-7    Is there a way to verify this after the fact?

Comment: that's what u did...but it doesn't appear to be bound.  Steps 29 and on...but see here too: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6015/using-the-ssl-installation-tool?locale=en

Comment: got "Results:No issues found." green box around server certificate, intermediate certificate and trusted root certificate.  BUT the server certificate still says it's only good till June 1st. Is this normal, does the actual one take over once that expires?

Comment: did you do an iisreset and reset the IIS services or website?  No, it won't simply take over.

Comment: didn't see anything about doing an 'iisreset'. Should I pick up on step 29 and try binding it and then do the iisreset?

Comment: went to bindings, selected one of the https' and clicked on edit just to check it out, the cert that expires 2 years from now is what is selected. So this means that it is binded. I should restart the website?

Comment: Delete the old certificate.  Or connect to the web site with a web browser, and see what certificate has been offered by the server.

Comment: if i go to the bindings for the site, it has 2 types for https. neither have a host name, both are on port 443. The IP address for the cert that expires soon is the local ip. The ip address for the cert that expires in 2015 is:  *      Does this help explain anything, am I screwed?

Answer (score 0):

Two https types were listed, changed the port on the intermediate certificate, then on the full certificate changed the IP to what the intermediate was using instead of *. Checked using godaddy's ssl verification tool and had the correct expiration date.